# Direction of translation/transcription

Tags: genetics, dna, terminology, mrna

Perhaps it would not be wrong to say that "translation/transcription goes in the direction of 3' to 5'" or "in the direction of 5' to 3'";that's because these statements are ambiguous, not specifying "XX's".

However, I am confused.
So I would like to clarify by clarifying the "XX's".

**My Question;**

> Are the following understanding correct?

**(1) Transcription;**
In the case of transcription, the RNA polymerase moves in the 3'→5' direction of the template strand of genome DNA, and the ribonucleotide attaches to the 3' side of the mRNA during synthesis, am I right?

**(2) Translation;**
In the case of translation, the ribosome moves (relatively) in the 5'→3' direction of the mRNA, and the amino acids are attached to the C-terminal side of the polypeptide, am I right?

**(3) Overall;**
The genetic code is "the sequence of the complementary strand of genomic DNA read in the 5'→3' direction, with T replaced by U". For example, if the sequence of the complementary strand of the genomic DNA is "5'-ATGTTT...termination codon-3'", the corresponding sequence of the mRNA is "5'-AUGUUU...termination codon-3'", which is "N-terminal - methionine - phenylalanine ...C-terminal" sequence.

Comment: The genetic code is a cypher: ATG=Met, UUU=Phe etc and nothing else. See the Wikipedia entry. I am sure the direction of transcription and translation are illustrated in the answers to other questions on this site. Please check. If not try Wikipedia or Berg online at NCBI bookshelf. Happy reading!

Comment: AUG, to be consistent  with UUU. The genetic code is a table of mRNA codon / amino acid equivalents, so U. However because one is usually doing conceptual translations of DNA in genomic sequences then one talks about ATG and TTT.

Comment: What I want to focus on is the direction of enzymes and synthesis.